# Accessing an array in multithreaded env causes app to crash

Tags: ios, multithreading

I have an `NSMutableArray` instance which is getting used in many places in my app. The array gets modified in a multithreaded environment within my app.

I am facing a crash when clearing this array. I have tried mutex locks, `@synchronized` block and GCD to solve the issue, but in vain.

Can anyone advice me how to resolve my issue?

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your array is already read by some code.
Try to declare you array as a property and make it atomic :

```
    @property (atomic,strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

Comment: i have added this property still crash the application

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers i have sort it out the problem, app crash issue is not with the array it was using Collection view i have used perform batch updates, by removing batch update i ihave used reload data

so my problem was solved